# Cleaner way to write ReactJS component

Tags: javascript, react.js

My code is as follows :

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import ReactCSSTransitionGroup from 'react-addons-css-transition-group';
import { filter_names } from './filterActions';
import Price from './price';
import Year from './year';
import Make from './make';
import Model from './model';
import Mileage from './mileage';
import Transmission from './transmission';
import Fuel from './fuel';

class filters extends React.Component {

    showFilters(filters){

        return filters.map(filter => {
            switch (filter.name){
                case filter_names.priceRange:
                    return <Price recap={filters.some(f => f.name === filter_names.priceRange)} title="Price" filters={filters} {...this.props}/>;
                case filter_names.year:
                    return <Year recap={filters.some(f => f.name === filter_names.year)} title="Year" filters={filters} {...this.props}/>;
                case filter_names.mileage:
                    return <Mileage recap={filters.some(f => f.name === filter_names.mileage)} title="Mileage" filters={filters} {...this.props}/>;
                case filter_names.fuel:
                    return <Fuel recap={filters.some(f => f.name === filter_names.fuel)} title="Fuel" filters={filters} {...this.props}/>;
                case filter_names.transmission:
                    return <Transmission recap={filters.some(f => f.name === filter_names.transmission)} title="Transmission" filters={filters} {...this.props}/>;
                default:
                    return true;
            }
        })
    }


    render(){
        const language = this.props.language;
        const filters = this.props.filters;

        return (
            <div className="filters noPadding col-xl-8 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
                <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionAppear={true} transitionAppearTimeout={500} transitionEnterTimeout={500} transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>
                    {this.showFilters(filters)}
                </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default filters;
```

Is there any way to write it on a cleaner way? I have in showFilter function all those components. Do I need to repeat it for every component or is there any simpler way to do it?

Comment: We all want to write cleaner code so please write in the title what your code does. What you want is implicit on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't shown any of the child components, but here's how I would approach this:

Instead of having each of your components be generated in a giant switch statement, I'd use an object that maps a component name to a component itself. Each of these components all have the same prop keys, they are just different components, right? *

Further, your `recap` value is completely pointless. If you're on that `switch` branch you don't need to do a `some` on the filter array to check if at least one element exists in the array with that name - you already know it does, because you're on that switch branch. As a result, I can simplify your `showFilters` method to:

```
const filterComponentMap = {
  priceRange: (props) => <Price title='Price' {...this.props} />
}

showFilters(filters, originalProps) {
  return filters.map((filter) => {
    return filterComponentMap[filter.name]({ filters, ...originalProps })
  }
}
```

You don't include the declaration of `filter_names`, but if you wanted to use the keys of those rather than raw strings you could always do:

```
const filterComponentMap = {
  [filter_actions.priceRange]: (props) => ..
}
```

Note that by convention we name variables `camelCase` and not `snake_case`, so rename that `filter_actions` to `filterActions`. Classes should be named `PascalCase`, and component should always follow that convention (even though components aren't always classes), so `filters` should be `Filters` (which is not a particularly good description either, by the way).

As your component is stateless there's no need to have the boilerplate of extending it from `React.Component`, you can instead use a simple function:

```
function showFilters(filters, originalProps) {
  ...
}

const Filters = ({ language, filters }) => {
  return <div className="filters noPadding col-xl-8 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
    <ReactCSSTransitionGroup transitionName="example" transitionAppear={true} transitionAppearTimeout={500} transitionEnterTimeout={500} transitionLeaveTimeout={500}>
      {showFilters(filters, this.props)}
    </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
  </div>
}

export default Filters
```

Consider using SASS (or some other preprocessor) and name your classes based on the component itself rather than the properties of the class. That is, instead of adding `.col-xs-8 .col-md-6` to your component declaration, add a single class to it (named `.filters` or something, using BEM or whatever you want to use - I prefer CSS modules) and style it in SASS with the Bootstrap mixins like so:

```
.filters {
  @extend make-col($grid-breakpoints.md, 6);
  @extend make-col($grid-breakpoints.xs, 8);
}
```

And store this file alongside the component file named `<ComponentName>.sass`.

---

* note that this could be further simplified by doing something like this instead (for some values of simplified)

```
const filterComponentMap = {
  priceRange: Price
}

showFilters(filters, originalProps) {
  return filters.map((filter) => {
    return <{filtersComponentMap[filter.name]} filters={filters} {...originalProps} />
  }
}
```

But this feels almost generic to a fault and breaks down as soon as you want to add some unique props (boolean values, for instance) to any of your components.